# C++ Exception Design Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, exception

I'd like to encapsulate Win32 errors (those returned from GetLastError()) in some form of exception class. Rather than having a single Win32 exception, however, I'd like to be able to have a specialized exception catchable for common errors, such as ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

For example, I'd have classes declared like this:

```
class WindowsException : public std::exception
{
public:
    static WindowsException Create(DWORD lastError);
    //blah

};

class ErrorAccessDeniedException : public WindowsException
{
public:
    //blah
};
```

However, I'd like the Win32 exception to be responsible for picking the right exception to return. That is, the thrower of the exception should look like:

```
int DangerousMethod() {
    throw WindowsAPI::WindowsException::Create(GetLastError());
}
```

and the catcher might look like:

```
try
{
    DangerousMethod();
} catch(WindowsAPI::ErrorAccessDeniedException ex)
{
    //Code for handling ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
} catch(WindowsAPI::WindowsException ex)
{
    //Code for handling other kinds of error cases.
}
```

My problem is that if the WindowsException::Create factory method returns a WindowsException, then the subtype (potentially ErrorAccessDeniedException) is sliced down to the base type. That is, the instance can't be polymorphic. I don't want to use a new'd pointer, because that would force the exception handler to delete it when it's done.

Does anyone know of a design solution that would be feasible for solving this problem elegantly?

Billy3

Comment: You could create a macro to declare a few different exception types, and create a factory for throwing based on the value of `GetLastError()`; but to be honest, I've only ever seen this problem approached like so: http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/trunk/lib/arch/XArchWindows.cpp

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesn't allow you to create specific catch handlers -- it's a single exception type for all exceptions of that type.

Comment: You should catch your exceptions by reference by the way, not by value as your above code sample currently shows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
int DangerousMethod() {
    throw WindowsAPI::WindowsException::Create(GetLastError());
}
```

To

```
int DangerousMethod() {
    WindowsAPI::WindowsException::Throw(GetLastError());
}
```

Meaning, instead of returning the exception then throwing it (which will slice, as you observed), have your helper/factory method throw it directly.

Comment: As I was reading the question I was inventing a convoluted solution where a static instance of every possible exception was maintained by the framework. Terry's solution is only "DUH Obvious" once you've seen it. (Either that, or we're both stupid :-)

Comment: What's wrong with `WindowsAPI::WindowsException::Throw()` and letting that function call `GetLastError()`?

Comment: You could -- I used the explicit GetLastError() in my example code to make it more clear what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

Some more exception handling background reading: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=373339

A note on type slicing and rethrowing:

> When rethrowing an exception  e  ,
>   prefer writing just  throw;   instead
>   of  throw e;   because the first form
>   always preserves polymorphism of the
>   rethrown object.

Comment: Not saying that's bad information, but ... what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: Just alerting to more possible slicing issues with exception handling.